# Show contents of div when overflow hidden

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, width, overflow

I have a website where a simple DIV will be hidden when it's width if overflow'ed.
The problem is on large layouts (1000px+) when there's enough width to show off the left & right side of the div - the content is hidden, yet I want it to show.

http://sadakov.com/ 
div #timeline #life - the width is enough to show content, yet hidden in the large browser;

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the section #timeline-section, you have a div .container. The bootstrap container class behaves like follow on medium screen :

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.container {
width: 750px;
}
.container {
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

Override the bootstrap with :

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    #timeline-section .container
    {
      width:100%;
    }
}
```